# My PHP PDO update counter in MYSQL does +3 instead of +1?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the amount of updates made on a record. The field name is pm_v. I got the following codes:

Update function:

```
function update_products_materials(){

 $query = "UPDATE
             " . $this->table_name . "
         SET
             pm_id = :pm_id1,
             pm_code = :pm_code,
             pm_name = :pm_name,
             pm_department = :pm_department,
             pm_temp = :pm_temp,
             pm_color = :pm_color,
             pm_v = pm_v +1
         WHERE
             pm_id = :pm_id2";

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

 $this->pm_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_id));
 $this->pm_code=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_code));
 $this->pm_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_name));
 $this->pm_department=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_department));
 $this->pm_temp=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_temp));
 $this->pm_color=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pm_color));

 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_id1', $this->pm_id);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_id2', $this->pm_id);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_code', $this->pm_code);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_name', $this->pm_name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_department', $this->pm_department);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_temp', $this->pm_temp);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pm_color', $this->pm_color);

 $stmt->execute();

 return $stmt;
  
}
```

This is the only place where I use pm_v.

The function is called in the following code:

```
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize objects
    $products_materials = new Products_Materials($db);
    $products_materials->id = $id;
    
    $products_materials->view_products_materials();
    $products_materials->update_products_materials();

if(isset($_POST["update"])){

    $products_materials->pm_id=$id;    
    $products_materials->pm_code=$_POST['pm_code'];
    $products_materials->pm_name=$_POST['pm_name'];
    $products_materials->pm_department=$_POST['pm_department'];
    $products_materials->pm_temp=isset($_POST['pm_temp']) ? $_POST['pm_temp'] : '';
    $products_materials->pm_color=isset($_POST['pm_color']) ? $_POST['pm_color'] : '';

    if($products_materials->update_products_materials() && (isset($_POST["update"]))){
        header("Location: view_products_materials.php?id={$id}"); 
        $_POST=array();

    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Unable to save record.</div>";
    }
}
```

Somehow, when I update a record it does +3 instead of +1. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can get it right?

Comment: Is `update_products_materials()` getting called in a loop?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I added the code where the function is called

Comment: You are calling it twice instead of once.. however wondering why it  gets +3 instead of +2 -- Maybe you call this function also in the constructor of `Products_Materials`?

Comment: Thanks, it somehow slipped 3 times in the file.